# Validating character string with ng-pattern

Tags: angularjs, ng-pattern

I want an ng-pattern expression to validate a textbox in AngularJS JavaScript. Contents for this textbox must have at least one Alphabetic character, but may also contain any number of Numeric and/or Special characters.

**Examples:**

1. `a1234$` It is acceptable (because 'a' is present)
2. `123%` It is not acceptable
3. `abc` It is acceptable
4. `56456a` It is acceptable
5. `123$%^abc` It is acceptable

Comment: Please post what you have tried so far.

Comment: Please note that this is a question and answer site, not a
code writing service. If you [edit] your question to
describe what you have tried so far and where you are stuck,
then we can try to help with specific problems. You should
also read [ask].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use ng-pattern like this.

```
<input type="text" ng-model="price" name="price_field" ng-pattern="/.*[a-zA-Z]+.*/" required>
```

Answer (score 0):

If all you need is to check if there is atleast one alphabet in the string you're matching then you can use the following pattern :

```
".*[a-zA-Z]+.*"
```

Comment: It's not working.......It allows to enter only alphabets in textbox....not numbers or special characters

Comment: Can you post the entire input tag where you are checking for the pattern?